# Accessing client IP using Atmosphere Framework

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, ip, atmosphere

There is a way to access client's IP using the Atmosphere Framework's AtmosphereResource or WebSocket?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
AtmosphereResource.getRequest().getRemoteAddr()
```